# Downloading a gunzipped file over FTP

Tags: php, ftp, gzip, gunzip

I am attempting to download a gunzipped file from an FTP server.

It appears to download successfully (correct file size, etc) but when I extract the contents, it fails stating that the data-format is violated.

If I manually download the same file using an FTP client like FileZilla, and then extract it, the extract works, which means my PHP for downloading the file is incorrect somehow.

Here is my code:

```
$this->_file = 'data.csv.gz';
$this->_directory = DOC_ROOT.'/imports/';

private function _loadFromFtpDataSource($url=null,$username=null,$password=null) {
    try {
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($url);
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, password);
        ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
        $handle = fopen($this->_directory . $this->_file, "w");
        ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $this->_file, FTP_ASCII, 0);            
        ftp_close($conn_id);
        fclose($handle);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->status = false;
        error_log("Failed to connect to ftp server");
    }
}
```

Can anyone see any reason why it may not be downloading correctly? Does special attention need to be taken when downloading a gunzipped file over FTP?

Comment: Not familiar with the php code but it could be down to binary/text mode for ftp.

Comment: *gzipped. gunzip is for unpacking gzipped files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $this->_file, FTP_ASCII, 0);
```

to

```
ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $this->_file, FTP_BINARY, 0);
```

you're transfering binary data archive (`...when I extract the contents...`) not a text file
read more on
http://www.coreftp.com/docs/web1/Ascii_vs_Binary_transfers.htm

Answer (score 1):

If the file does not use purely ASCII (e.g. UTF-8 instead), your download will most likely get corrupted. If you change the mode from FTP_ASCII to FTP_BINARY, you should be alright.

Comment: Thank you, this was correct. I have marked @Marek Sebera's answer as correct as he posted it first.

Answer (score 1):

Binary files need to download in `binary` mode not `ascii` mode

```
$this->_file = 'data.csv.gz';
$this->_directory = DOC_ROOT.'/imports/';

private function _loadFromFtpDataSource($url=null,$username=null,$password=null) {
    try {
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($url);
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, password);
        ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
        $handle = fopen($this->_directory . $this->_file, "w");
        ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $this->_file, FTP_BINARY, 0);            
        ftp_close($conn_id);
        fclose($handle);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->status = false;
        error_log("Failed to connect to ftp server");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was correct. I have marked @Marek Sebera's answer as correct as he posted it first.